# Drupal Custom Comment Module

Tags: 6, forms, comments

I am trying to create my first module in drupal 6.
I just need to add some new fields to the already existing comment form(comment module).
Eg: City,Email and state fields.

I have created 2 files:
1. mmcomment.module
2. mmcomment.info

Used a function `hook_form_alter()` like this:

```
 function mmcomment_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { // form override
 if ($form_id == 'comment_form') {
    // unset the other field elements

    $form['subject'] = array(
      '#access' => FALSE
    );
    $form['comment_filter']['comment'] = array(
      '#access' => FALSE
    );
    // add field to all comments

    $form['Email'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Email Address'),
      '#maxlength' => 255,
      '#size' => 30,
      '#required' => 1,
      '#weight' => 1,
      '#default_value' => $email
    );
     $form['displayName'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Display Name'),
      '#maxlength' => 255,
      '#size' => 30,
      '#weight' => 2,
      '#default_value' => $displayName
    );

    $form['_author'] = array(
      '#access' => FALSE
    );
    $form['author'] = array(
      '#access' => FALSE
    );
```

I need to get the form values and insert into DB.
What Function can I use for the same.
I have tried:
hook_nodeapi(mmcomment_nodeapi).
But can't get the form values.
Any suggestions..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$form` structure you have to add/override the submit (and maybe the validate) handler.